# How can I run a bash command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, scripting

I have a script in Ruby and inside has to run a `bash` command. This command is an `export http_proxy = ""` and `export https_proxy = ""`.

The problem is that I run the following, without running errors, but appears that doesn't make any change:

```
system "export http_proxy=''"
system "export https_proxy=''"
```

I created a `file.sh` with this lines and if I run it in a terminal only works when run: `source file.sh` or `. file.sh`.

Could you please help me how I can run this commands in the Ruby script? It can be directly with the command lines or executing an `.sh` file in the script.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a separate process using `system`, any changes made to the environment of that process affects that process only, and will disappear when the process exits.

That exactly why running `file.sh` won't change your current shell since it runs it as a sub-shell, and the changes disappear when the process exits.

As you've already discovered, using `source` or `.` runs *deoes* affect the current shell but that's because it runs the script not as a sub-shell, but within the context of the *current* shell.

If you want to change the environment variables of the current Ruby script, you should look into [`ENV`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/ENV.html), something like:

```
ENV["http_proxy"]  = ""
ENV["https_proxy"] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%x( echo 'hi' )
```

and to capture standard output in a variable

```
var = %x( echo 'hi' )
```